# SCCM task sequence fails after Apply Operating System - Error 0x80004005

Tags: sccm-2012

I'm an IT admin just learning SCCM and I'm dead stumped on what is causing an error I've been seeing with my operating system deployment task sequence.  When I try to image a computer with the task sequence, the task sequence succeeds up until the point that it needs to move on to the next step after installing the operating system, which should be installing needed drivers.  Instead, it fails with the generic error 0x08004005. This always occurs right after the image is applied.  The image is applying just fine, if I watch the progress of the task sequence, I can see all of the normal Windows folders going on the C:/ drive, which is what I want.  This doesn't seem to make a difference afterwards, though, because the operating system does not boot after this happens.  Here is what I've tried so far:

- Created a new task sequence

  - Created a new Task sequence media
  - Created
    a new boot image
  - Added WinPE drivers to boot image
  - Removed drivers
    from boot image
- Scaled down the whole task sequence to just be
  partition the HDD and install Windows.

I can send my SMSTS.log as well if needed.  I don't see anything really noteworthy there, but maybe there's something I've missed.  Thank you in advance for your help!

EDIT : I've added the parts of my SMSTS.log that contain the error code.

```
Executing as a standalone exe   TSManager   764 (0x02FC)
Initializing TS Environment TSManager   764 (0x02FC)
Opening Task Sequencing Environment TSManager   764 (0x02FC)
Env variable _SMSTSProtectedPaths set to
%OSDStateStorePath%;%_SMSTSClientCache%;%_SMSTSNewClientCachePathToCleanup%
TSManager   764 (0x02FC)
**!sVolumeID.empty(), HRESULT=80004005 (e:\qfe\nts\sms\framework\tscore\resolvesource.cpp,465)  TSManager   764 (0x02FC)**
Deleting volume ID file C:\_SMSTSVolumeID.7159644d-f741-45d5-ab29-0ad8aa4771ca ...  TSManager   764 (0x02FC)
DeleteFileW(sVolumeIDFile.c_str()), HRESULT=80070002 (e:\qfe\nts\sms\framework\tscore\resolvesource.cpp,508)    TSManager   764 (0x02FC)


  !sVolumeID.empty(), HRESULT=80004005 (e:\qfe\nts\sms\framework\tscore\resolvesource.cpp,465)  TSManager   764 (0x02FC)

Initializing TS Environment TSManager   764 (0x02FC)
Opening Task Sequencing Environment TSManager   764 (0x02FC)
Env variable _SMSTSProtectedPaths set to %OSDStateStorePath%;%_SMSTSClientCache%;%_SMSTSNewClientCachePathToCleanup%    TSManager   764 (0x02FC)
**!sVolumeID.empty(), HRESULT=80004005 (e:\qfe\nts\sms\framework\tscore\resolvesource.cpp,465)  TSManager   764 (0x02FC)**
Deleting volume ID file C:\_SMSTSVolumeID.7159644d-f741-45d5-ab29-0ad8aa4771ca ...  TSManager   764 (0x02FC)
DeleteFileW(sVolumeIDFile.c_str()), HRESULT=80070002 (e:\qfe\nts\sms\framework\tscore\resolvesource.cpp,508)    TSManager   764 (0x02FC)
**!sVolumeID.empty(), HRESULT=80004005 (e:\qfe\nts\sms\framework\tscore\resolvesource.cpp,465)  TSManager   764 (0x02FC)**
```

Comment: Fairly common error, although the solution escapes me at the moment. The best thing you can do though is find and post your SMSTS.log file into your question, or at least the 20 lines before and after the 0x80004005 error, as those logs can get pretty long. Be sure to sanitize any corp. Information if you need to, as that will become googlable after that.

Comment: I added those pieces of the log that I think might be relevant. Let me know if more is needed.